# Is there a way to higlight items in a Custom Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have a custom DataGrid filled with a list of items, and I want to change the item's row color when I double click them.

I'm trying to do it using DataTriggers binded to a bool property in each item, but it's not working.
I can see that the bool property it's actually changing to "false", but that change is not reflecting in the UI.

XAML Code:

```
<controlGrid:CustomDataGrid 
              Grid.Row="2"              
              Grid.Column="1" 
              MinHeight="100" 
              MaxHeight="650"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              AlternationCount="2"
              CanUserAddRows ="False"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                  
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

C# ViewModel

```
    private ICollectionView _items;
    public ICollectionView Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _cuentas = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        }
    }

    private Item selectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get => selectedItem;
        set
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            SelectedItem.Selected = false;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
     {

  private void DoubleClickInteraction()
  {
      foreach (var item in Items.Cast<Item>().Where(c => c.Id ==    SelectedItem.Id)
      {
          item.SeleccionadaPreviamente = false;
      }
  }
```

Custom DataGrid

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItemsList", typeof(IList), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreSelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PreSelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public CustomDataGrid()
    {
        this.SelectionChanged += CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }

    public void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;
    }
```

Tried changing the property directly on the selected item property, and iterating over all the list and changing when the item id matches with the selected item, but still nothing : (
Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the custom control defined and why don't you use the built-in one?

Comment: I'm not the one who coded this, so I don't know what's the need to use a custom DataGrid.
Don't know what dou you mean by "how is the custom control defined", but i added the class just in case.